# Eager Loading: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<project.Models.A> to project.Models.A

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the foreign key of table **B** and the project seems to work and continue without error but when you look at the database the foreign key column of table **A** it produces null and there is no key coming from table **B**. I did a little bit of research and found out that eager loading might be the solution.

```
 [HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    List<B> b = _db.BBs.ToList();

    List<B> eager_b = _db.BBs.Include(t => t.A).ToList();

    foreach (var c in b)
    {
        c.A = _db.AAs.Where(t => t.BId == c.BId).ToList();
        //_db.AAs.Where(t => t.BId == c.BId).ToList(); (PRODUCES THE SQUIGGLY)
    }

    return View();
}
```

But programming being programming a solution leads to another error. How come it can't convert it into a list when we've already converted it into a list before we even did anything with it?

I want to get the foreign key and just output it into the View, I guess it doesn't have to show into the database (as bad as that sounds)

I am using EntityFrameworkCore 8 and sqlserver 8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please verify what is the `Type` of `task.A`? I believe it might be `A` instead of `List<A>`.

Comment: In C# when we write classes with properties, we have a choice of using singular or plural names. We adopt the convention of using singular for non collections and plurals for collections. This helps us out later when we try and do something like `person.Name = new string[]{"John"}`. Because name is singular it is highly obvious we cannot assign a multi value array to a single value property. In your case if a B has a single A it should be that a B is a child of A, because children have one parent. Any given A will have a list of Bs as parents can have more than one child. You cannot assign...

Comment: ... a List (created by ToList) to a singular property. If you're trying to download a single entity, use e.g. FirstOrDefault rather than Where/ToList. Of course if you've written the code so that a singularly named A truly is a list, then you've created a recipe for confusing yourself and you should change that. All in, there is no point downloading all the Bs in the database then running a loop that fires off one query at a time loading A objects one by one; it's incredibly inefficient. Just use eagerB (do not use underscores in local variable names) as it already has the data you loop for